# Cannot update homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm not sure what to do about this specific error. Before, it asked me to delete specific paths (which I did) but I don't understand what it means by Could not link.

```
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
fossil
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
brew doctor
```

It fixes broken links. After it's completed run:

```
brew upgrade
brew update
```